# How to track AWS endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-comprehend

I created an Amazon Web Services endpoint of a classifier and kept it running for sometime and then deleted i.I need to know for how long that endpoint was running so i could estimate the total cost incurred.Does AWS keep track of endpoints?
How do i access that information?

Comment: I think in the billiing you can get the duration and cost after some time before the billing period.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cloudtrail audits to lookout for when CreateEndpoint API was called and when DeleteEndpoint was called . Go to Cloudtrail Console (Event history page ) and search for EventName `CreateEndpoint` and `DeleteEndpoint`